# Isomorphisms between cyclic groups

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, cyclic-groups, chinese-remainder-theorem

I was solving an exercise which asked to determine all abelian groups of order 48 two by two not isomorphic with each other and it seemed natural to me to use in the process the following proposition:
$$ \Bbb{N}_a\times\Bbb{N}_b \simeq \Bbb{N}_{ab} \iff MCD(a,b)=1$$
I looked up in my notes but I have not properly found an answer to this although I believe it comes from the Chinese Remainder Theorem; can someone tell me if it's true and if it is explain me why it is? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: the *exponent* of a group $G$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $g^n=e$ for all $g\in G$. What is the exponent of $\Bbb N_a\times\Bbb N_b$?

Comment: $mcm(a,b)$; which is exactly $a\cdot b $ when $MCD(a,b)=1$